# Subpoena Duces Tecum - who to contact regarding disclosure of company records

Tags: united-states, california, civil-law

Mostly hypothetical subpoena duces tecum.
How would I ask a company for the contact information and whatever else that I would need in order to prepare for a subpoena for data, documents, & records related to my account/interactions with that company?

Would I need to talk to someone in the legals dept? Some executive officer? who has the authority to divulge company information and records?

What is the extent of the information that I would be able to obtain? *I assume this would be just the documents related to the court case at hand?*
*I reside in California.*

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get evidence from the company? Are you suing them or are you defending them?

Comment: @Viktor Does it matter? Can they do something like plead the 5th if I was trying to sue them?

Comment: You can't just go on random fishing expeditions.

Comment: lol? i dont really go fishing.

Comment: @Viktor this is mostly hypothetical/educational. i will 92% not be going through with the subpoena (or the suing) due to the court costs/fees outweighing the benefit, but I like to be prepared for everything... and learning it is interesting to me too =P

Comment: Where does this occur? Are you just asking them or are you serving them with a court order or summons?

Comment: Jurisdiction tag needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I ask a company for the contact information and whatever else
>   that  I would need in order to prepare for a subpoena for data, documents,
>   &  records related to my account/interactions with that company?

Contact the company and ask them who you should direct your subpoena duces decum (SDT) to. Be specific and ask them about why type of records they keep, if they require account numbers. Also ask them about what format they will produce the information.

> Would I need to talk to someone in the legals dept? Some executive 
>   officer? who has the authority to divulge company information and records?

This really depends on the company. I am a practicing attorney and found that the larger phone and internet companies have published SDT guidelines and dedicated compliance folks. These requests almost always go through or involve the company's legal department. However, the smaller the company, the less likely there is to be a legal department.